# Identifying FK's in a MySQL database that were not defined upon database creation?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

A database was created with 5 tables. These tables were populated with data upon creation - perhaps it was imported from a previous database.

When the DB was created, primary keys were created for each table, however foreign keys were not.

How do I run a query to identify which tables columns contain data that relates to the PK in other tables? Effectively, how do I identify the FK column(s) on each table? Some tables may contain 2 FK's.

The end goal is to identify the FK('s) in each table and properly set up the table with appropriate FK structure and table relations.

Comment: If the columns have not been included in a foreign key, how would you identify them?  If it's a manual process of identifying which columns are FKs, that doesn't seem arduous for 5 tables.

Comment: If you follow good naming conventions, the FK will be named something like `othertablename_id`

Comment: While these are both true:
1) maybe the DB has 50 tables, maybe some tables have multiple FKs
2) maybe the naming conventions were not up to you, maybe you're inheriting a terrible DB and making changes because the last guy didn't know what the FK he was doing (pun intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to use queries to automate this database design / reverse-engineering process.  (If you had 500 tables, maybe. But you only have five.)

Eyeball your table definitions. If you have, for example, an `id` primary key column in your `user` table, your `contact` table might have a `user_id` column. That is the FK to `user.id`. It will help you greatly if you really understand how your tables tie together with FKs.

And, keep in mind that your system will still work tolerably well if you don't bother to actually declare these foreign keys. What you'll lose:

- constraints, in which the database engine prevents, for example a `contact.user_id` column value that doesn't point to any `user.id` row.
- possibly some helpful indexing.

[MySql Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) has a [reverse engineering feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-live.html). It inspects the definition of a database and does its best to sort out various [entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) (tables) and the [relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) (foreign key dependencies) between them. It presents graphical [e:r diagrams](https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Entity_relationship_diagramming) and can generate [DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html).  That can help you understand a database and set up appropriate FKs. But still, check the relationships it suggests: this data is yours, not Workbench's.

Comment: For the sake of this argument, let's say there are more than 5. What if there were 100?

You're right, this is something that should be easy enough to discern by hand with just 5 tables, and I can see the relations plain enough, but this is a problem that's been given to me and I don't know the answer. I'm supposed to find a way to do it in MySQL Workbench I don't even know where to begin looking.

Comment: Workbench has a reverse-engineering feature, in which it loads up a live database or a sql script and tries to sort out various relationships.  Is that what you mean? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-live.html

Comment: I think it is. I'll take a look at the link. Thanks.